# How to split a list string based on \n

Tags: python, list, strip

I have a list like this:

`['Sehingga 8 Ogos 2021: Jumlah kes COVID-19 yang dilaporkan adalah 18,688 kes (1,262,540 kes)\n\nPecahan setiap negeri (Kumulatif):\n\nSelangor - 6,565 (465,015)\nWPKL - 1,883 (140,404)\nJohor - 1,308 (100,452)\nSabah -Lagi 1,379 (93,835)\nSarawak - 581 (81,328)\nNegeri Sembilan - 1,140 (78,777)\nKedah - 1,610 (56,598)\nPulau Pinang - 694 (52,368)\nKelantan - 870 (49,433)\nPerak - 861 (43,924)\nMelaka - 526 (35,584)\nPahang - 602 (29,125)\nTerengganu - 598 (20,696)\nWP Labuan - 2 (9,711)\nWP Putrajaya - 63 (4,478)\nPerlis - 6 (812)\n\n- KPK KKM']`

How can i get a certain word based on the start and end position of \n.

Expected output:

1)`Sehingga 8 Ogos 2021`

2)`Selangor - 6,565 (465,015)`

3)`WPKL - 1,883 (140,404)`

4)`Johor - 1,308 (100,452)`

and so on ..

Comment: You're looking for `split()`, not `strip()`

Comment: @PranavHosangadi my bad, i had changed the title

Comment: You need to more precisely define *why* that is the expected output.  You only take part of the first line - is that because of the colon, or some other reason?  You ignore the second line completely - is that because of the lack of numbers?  What other exceptional cases exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `re` module for the task:

```py
import re

lst = [
    "Sehingga 8 Ogos 2021: Jumlah kes COVID-19 yang dilaporkan adalah 18,688 kes (1,262,540 kes)\n\nPecahan setiap negeri (Kumulatif):\n\nSelangor - 6,565 (465,015)\nWPKL - 1,883 (140,404)\nJohor - 1,308 (100,452)\nSabah -Lagi 1,379 (93,835)\nSarawak - 581 (81,328)\nNegeri Sembilan - 1,140 (78,777)\nKedah - 1,610 (56,598)\nPulau Pinang - 694 (52,368)\nKelantan - 870 (49,433)\nPerak - 861 (43,924)\nMelaka - 526 (35,584)\nPahang - 602 (29,125)\nTerengganu - 598 (20,696)\nWP Labuan - 2 (9,711)\nWP Putrajaya - 63 (4,478)\nPerlis - 6 (812)\n\n- KPK KKM"
]

out = []
for v in lst:
    for g in re.findall(r"^(.*?\(.*?\))\n", v, flags=re.M):
        out.append(g.split(":")[0])

print(*out, sep="\n")
```

Prints:

```
Sehingga 8 Ogos 2021
Selangor - 6,565 (465,015)
WPKL - 1,883 (140,404)
Johor - 1,308 (100,452)
Sabah -Lagi 1,379 (93,835)
Sarawak - 581 (81,328)
Negeri Sembilan - 1,140 (78,777)
Kedah - 1,610 (56,598)
Pulau Pinang - 694 (52,368)
Kelantan - 870 (49,433)
Perak - 861 (43,924)
Melaka - 526 (35,584)
Pahang - 602 (29,125)
Terengganu - 598 (20,696)
WP Labuan - 2 (9,711)
WP Putrajaya - 63 (4,478)
Perlis - 6 (812)
```

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what i want. Btw i tried to get the output one by one like this `print(*out[0], sep="\n")` but the result is showing vertically. Do you have any idea why does this happen?

Comment: @terry555 `out[0]` is string. Try `print(out)` to print the entire list of strings.

Comment: Thanks for your respond, I just figured it out after I posted haha

Comment: Btw sometime the `Sehingga 8 Ogos 2021: ` will become `Sehingga 8 Ogos 2021. ` How can I add a `or` statement  for ":" and "."

Comment: @terry555 Try `g.split(":")[0].split(".")[0]`

Comment: I tried ` out.append(g.split(":")[0].split(".")[0])` But the [0] index is start from Selangor - 5,740 (470,755). I had asked another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68710367/inconsistent-index-value-in-re-module/68710547#68710547) for more details, you can have a look. Thanks